# How to load Kibana3 dashboards into Kibana4?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have recently installed Kibana4 but I am beginning to understand that dashboards are designed differently from Kibana3 i.e., to embed multiple visualizations which are designed individually into every dashboard. I already have a lot of dashboards designed in Kibana3 so I would like to know if there is a way to load them to kibana4 instead of creating everything from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best I know, there is no way to do that. Not just the formats, but the queries sent to ES backend are quite different. Kibana 3 used to use facets a lot for segmentation which is a deprecated feature and Kibana4 got rid of that.

Comment: Well I understand that but my question was about how to load the dashboards.  These are just JSONs and elasticsearch queries are not embedded in them right? So I thought there shouldn't be much of a problem in loading them. Not sure how to do that though.

Comment: Sure, you can load the JSON from the Kibana3 definition into Kibana4.  What you can't do it use it as a dashboard, for all the reasons previously given.

Comment: Dashboards are saved in "kibana-int"(default) index on your ES instance. You can download all those docs which as you mentioned are just JSONs. These have both definition of a dashboard (eg- timestamp, refresh_interval) and ES queries say if you panel is having a histogram of dates, you will find a histogram facet in the corresponding ES doc for the dashboard. Both dashboard specific information and ES specific queries are changed a lot in K4 and hence your existing dashboards may not be of much use.
You can however keep running both K3 and K4 on ES and use the old one until migration is done.