# Create dashboard automatically using file-system in Kibana4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

In Kibana-3x, I was copying the .json file to `<kibana>/app/dashboards` directory directly, so that it was building the dashboard automatically. How I will achieve the same in Kibana 4.1.0?

have a number of auto-generated dashboards that I need to "upload" to Kibana. The preferred means of uploading is to drop the .json into the app/dashboards directory. Would that be possible with Kibana-4.1.0?

Answer (score 1):

You question is indeed similar to [this Kibana4 GitHub issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2310) (now entitled "enhancement" request). The request in that issue is about using javascripts whereas you want to do it using json. I haven't tried uploading a dashboard this way since I got introduced to Kibana directly in the 4.x version but I'm afraid that you cannot do this at all in 4.x as of now.

EDIT:
I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568193/how-to-load-kibana3-dashboards-into-kibana4) that addresses something on Kibana Dashboard json files. You might want to check that out, maybe?

Comment: hmm, I saw that, Anyway thanks, For time being i am using kibana-3, lets wait for next release.